# Why do i have to surround n with list twice to get the proper result?

Tags: scheme, racket

```
(define (all-sublists buffer n)
  (cond ((= n 0) n)
        ((all-sublists (append buffer (list (list n)) (map (lambda (x) (append (list n) x)) buffer)) (- n 1)))))
```

the result looks like this:

```
(all-sublists '((3) (2) (2 3) (1) (1 3) (1 2) (1 2 3)) 0)
```

when there is only one list around n:

```
(define (all-sublists buffer n)
  (cond ((= n 0) n)
        ((all-sublists (append buffer (list n) (map (lambda (x) (append (list n) x)) buffer)) (- n 1)))))
```

the results get a dotted pair:

```
(all-sublists '(3 2 (2 . 3) 1 (1 . 3) (1 . 2) (1 2 . 3)) 0)
```

Comment: In their current form, both procedures are simply returning zero instead of performing any useful job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is not that you have "to surround n with list twice to get the proper result", the truth is that there are several problems with your code, for starters: the last condition of a `cond` should start with an `else`, and you're using `append` incorrectly. If I understood correctly, you just want the powerset of a list:

```
(define (powerset aL)
  (if (empty? aL)
      '(())
      (let ((rst (powerset (rest aL))))
        (append (map (lambda (x) (cons (first aL) x))
                     rst)
                rst))))
```

Like this:

```
(powerset '(1 2 3))
=> '((1 2 3) (1 2) (1 3) (1) (2 3) (2) (3) ())
```